# SQLite Pivot and Cross Tab Queries

Tags: .net, sqlite, pivot, crosstab

Is there any way to create a pivot and/or cross-tab query using for SQLite using any of the available .NET wrappers?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this totally helps, but this link explains how to do basic pivots with the case statement:
http://softwaresalariman.blogspot.com/2008/05/pivot-table-hack-in-sqlite3-and-mysql.html